# Scala: regex with string interpolation for match

Tags: regex, scala

I have two regex that I want to merge in one final regex to match text against this. Is there a way to get it with string interpolation or the right way is different?

```
val regex1 = "....".r
val regex2 = "....".r

val finalRegex = "^($regex1)(?:($regex2))$".r
```

is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
val finalRegex = s"^(${regex1.regex})(?:(${regex2.regex}))$$".r
```